# How to solve CORS policy error in hybrid app which uses angular 6 ,ionic 4 as front end and scala as back end?

Tags: json, angular, scala, ionic-framework

I am trying to use GET method for login purpose, Using following code:

```
 login(data){
 return this.http.get("http://Server_IP:88/mLogin/" + 
 data.controls['mobile'].value + "/" + 
 data.controls['password'].value,{}).pipe(tap(
    res=>{console.log('User: '+res)},
    err=>console.log(err) ));
 }
```

Above code works fine on chrome browser and getting a response too. but it does not work when build APK i.e. it does not work on the device. and when we inspect application it gets a response in the console but gives the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://Server_IP:88/mLog' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my scala (server code):

```
  `nextFilter(requestHeader)
   .map { result =>
    if (requestHeader.method.equals("OPTIONS")) {
     Results.Ok.withHeaders(
    Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
    Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "X-Requested- 
     With, 
    Accept, Content-Type",
    Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> 
    "OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE")
   } else {
   result.withHeaders(
   Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
    Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "X-Requested- 
    With, Accept, Content-Type",
 Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> 
  "HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE",
   Http.HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS -> "X-Custom- 
  Header-To-Expose")
      }
      }`
```

Comment: Youll have to set the CORS Header 'acces-control-allow-origin' to '*' (on the server)  in order to allow requests from every client. Tell me if this worked, ill create an answer then

Comment: we already using

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. DoubleCheck the server-script if you set the header. (On the Preflight Request which is of type OPTIONS)

Comment: please check my updated post with server-side code

Comment: Test the API with Postman or something different and check if the header is actually sent. someone else has to provide Scala-expertise for that

Comment: thanks for your help